# Get username from auth ticket in sqldatasource where condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following cookie on login:
   if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
            {
                string userData = "ApplicationSpecific data for this user.";

```
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
              UserName.Text,
              DateTime.Now,
              DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
              isPersistent,
              userData,
              FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            // Encrypt the ticket.
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            // Create the cookie.
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, isPersistent);
        }
```

And in the protected page I decrypt it:

```
 HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
```

And there's a gridview control in the protected page.

- When I'm choosing to bind the gridview from sqldatasource , I need to
  select The database and I can use the 'Where' clause.

For example:

```
Column : Username
Operator : =
Source : control/cookie/form/profile/queryString/session/route.
```

I've choosed COOKIE because of the

```
forms auth ticket. and the cookie name from web.config:

     <forms name=".TEST"
```

But is not working I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following to web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

As that is showing you the error message that is being hidden. What we are currently seeing a generic "Error message denied".

Alternatively you may wish to look at a better error handling system like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) in which errors are logged to the DB and you can still have restrictive errors but still be able to as a developer see what they are.

Comment: ok I've found how to fix it , but now How can I get the name from the cookie in the sqldatasource?

Comment: can't you set a DefaultValue (or hook onto the onNeedDataSource) and use User.Name ?

Comment: I can't set a default value because when the user logs in , I will show some information in a gridview based on his username , and I have no other idea.